# Converting synthetic function "<<" in Scala to MongoDB command

Tags: mongodb, scala, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to update some fields in the `MongoDB` Shell using the `aggregation framework`. I actually am wanting to convert the ip addresses currently as a `String` type in the `collection` into a `Long` type and so need to convert the following `scala` code into `MongoDB` command:

```
   def ipv4ToLong(ip: String): Option[Long] = Try(
     ip.split('.').ensuring(_.length == 4)
       .map(_.toLong).ensuring(_.forall(x => x >= 0 && x < 256))
       .reverse.zip(List(0,8,16,24)).map(xi => xi._1 << xi._2).sum
   ).toOption
```

I've been able to convert most of this using the [MongoDB Aggregation documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) but I am having some trouble with this part: `xi._1 << xi._2`

From the my IDE prompts; I can see that this (`<<`) is a synthetic function relating to `scala byte` ([as seen here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Byte.html)) and is defined as:

> Returns this value bit-shifted left by the specified number of bits,
>   filling in the new right bits with zeroes.

Any idea if there is a similar function to use in the `MongoDB` commands or operators? Or an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate answering my own question - it's always better if someone can help out but sadly not on this occasion and it might save someone some time. I was eventually able to locate some more information about [bit-shift operators here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work#answer-141873). I can see that the function `<<` takes two numerical types (e.g. `Long`, `Int`, etc) and as suggested the bits are shifted to the left. As mentioned; I am trying to equate this to implement in `MongoDB` as there isn't an equivalent function. But that link was effective in breaking this down. So:

```
    a << b = a * 2^b
```

And using `MongoDB` operators (as originally intended) this would be:

```
    $multiply: [a, { $pow: [2, b]}]
```